# How to manage MySQL table with huge number of rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table `user_history` with 7 million records. I would like to know how to manage this table with the following criteria:

I have more than 2 million record of 2012 year, which are not widely used now, that means user only views his history sometimes.

Now what are the options to manage this table? Should I need to delete rows for year 2012? How do Social media sites (Facebook, Twitter) manage their user history?

Comment: That's a very long debate. But for Facebook and Twitter 7m is piece of cake. However you could archive old records if those are not important and you could also Partition your table based on the Year. There are many techniques, Google will help a lot.

Comment: 7 million rows is large, but not huge. Don't worry about it. But have a look at partitioning for when it gets a little bigger.

Comment: Partition mysql table http://www.chrismoos.com/2010/01/31/mysql-partitioning-tables-with-millions-of-rows

Answer (score 1):

One of the best way to handle large tables are to use partition.

It's like creating a lot a small tables, except Mysql does it for, for reading and writing, based on a column, which is the partition key.

More informations here : http://www.chrismoos.com/2010/01/31/mysql-partitioning-tables-with-millions-of-rows